# Coloring points in a geom_qq plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to color the points in a `geom_qq` (alias `stat_qq`) quantile-quantile plot based on some variable that is associated with them.

An example would be coloring the points of a quantile-quantile plot of `mtcars$mpg` based on the values of `mtcars$disp`, which I have attempted in various ways:

```
library(ggplot2)
pA = ggplot(mtcars) + geom_qq(aes(sample = mpg))
pB = ggplot(mtcars) + geom_qq(aes(sample = mpg, color=disp))
pC = ggplot(mtcars) + geom_qq(aes(sample = mpg, fill=disp), shape=21)
pD = ggplot(mtcars) + geom_qq(aes(sample = mpg, color=as.factor(disp)))

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(pA,pB,pC,pD,labels=LETTERS[1:4])
```

[image: Failure to color stat_qq points]

Unfortunately, the points only appear colored when `mtcars$disp` is treated as a categorical variable (**D**), in which case the data yields several series of points for which the theoretical quantiles are calculated separately (such that their pattern changes).

I would like mtcars$disp to be treated as a continuous variable that dictates the color of each point, which I can do manually:

```
manual_colors = colorRampPalette(c("blue","red"))(100)[as.numeric(cut(mtcars$disp,breaks=100))]
ggplot(mtcars) + geom_qq(aes(sample = mpg), color=manual_colors)
```

[image: Desired result]

What would the proper ggplot2 syntax be to achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geom_qq` doesn't seem to be able to allow this. In theory, if you could change [this line](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/9869339607d342d5d7dc7982586d20d54265a321/R/stat-qq.r#L89) from

```
data.frame(sample, theoretical)
```

to

```
data.frame(sample, theoretical, data)
```

it would probably work, but it's not obvious to me the easiest way to attempt that.

Instead I recommend you just calculate the values yourself. It's pretty simple. you can use a function like this

```
make_qq <- function(dd, x) {
    dd<-dd[order(dd[[x]]), ]
    dd$qq <- qnorm(ppoints(nrow(dd)))
    dd
}
```

And then you can make the plot like this

```
ggplot(make_qq(mtcars, "mpg")) + 
    geom_point(aes(x=qq, y=mpg, color=hp)) + 
    labs(x="Theoretical",y="Observed")
```

[image]